# How do I make my discord bot auto respond to any message

Tags: discord, discord.js

What I am trying to do is set up an autoresponse discord bot that adds a reaction to any message that is being sent,in a specific channel. I cannot figure out why it is not showing up in discord.

Comment: Well we can't help you out if you don't provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, just add a message event listener, validate if the channel id is the one you want it to be, and then use the [`.react`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages) method. For example:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.id !== 'channel id here') return;
  message.react('emoji here')
// if you want to use a custom emoji put it's id there instead.
})
```

Comment: Thanks japanballdev, helped a lot